# Drag and Drop Element into a Container fails with too many elements

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to use Drag and Drop to move `<li>` elements from one `<ul>` to another `<ul>`.  I've got it working up to a point.  My problem is I can't "drop" a `<li>` element when it's over another `<li>` element in my `<ul>` container.  So when I fill up the visible portion of my container I can no longer drag and drop.

This [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPrLRy?editors=101) demonstrates my problem.

Answer (score 0):

not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, if you want the drop target
to enlarge to accomodate, then be sure you set the CSS style on the target
with a text size using px definitions instead of pt specs.

then each time a drop occurs add to your drop routine to increase the size
of the drop target by the pixel height of 1 line of text. so it grows by 1 on
every drop, or the height is equal to lineHeight x (numElements + 1)
always leaving you room for 1 more drop

if you are trying to maintain a fixed size of the drop target, ie, you dont want
to move other elements down the page, take the above mentioned drop target
and put it inside a fixed size div with scrollable properties.

that way you have a drop element that can grow as described above,
but the fixed div constrains the screen real estate so the drop target doesnt
take up more space than you want

Comment: I don't want my <ul> element to increase in size.  Currently it is fixed size and if enough <li> elements are put inside it will have a scrollbar.  My problem is that when my <ul> has 6 <li> elements it no longer has any empty space, which makes dropping any more <li> elements impossible.  I want to be able to continue to drop more <li> elements.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue.  I had to comment out an if statement in my handleDragOver function that was checking if the event.target was the dropzone element. I also changed my handleDrop function to use event.currentTarget instead of event.target